# Remove an element from html()?

Tags: jquery, html, click, parents

How can I remove certain element inside html()?

For instance, I have this html links,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="string-comment">Comment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="string-delete-needle">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="string-publish-needle">Publish</a></li>
</ul>
```

When you click on the class of `string-publish-needle`, I will store the html in a variable,

```
var html_parents = object_parents.html();

<li><a href="#" class="string-comment">Comment</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="string-delete-needle">Delete</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="string-publish-needle">Publish</a></li>
```

and I want to remove this one which is the `parent` of `string-publish-needle`,

```
<li><a href="#" class="string-publish-needle">Publish</a></li>
```

so I can have a new html content below only,

```
<li><a href="#" class="string-comment">Comment</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="string-delete-needle">Delete</a></li>
```

My code but does not work of course!

```
$('.string-publish-needle').click(function(e){

    var object = $(this);
    var object_path = object.attr('href');
    var object_parent = object.parent('li');
    var object_parents = object.parents('ul');
    var html_parents = object_parents.html();
    var html_remain = object_parents.html().remove(object_parent);

    alert(html_remain);

});
```

Comment: What are you doing with the HTML? Why can't you work with DOM elements?

Comment: have a look on page here - http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/jquery.plugin.reload.self/

when you click on the delete the entire `<ul>` will be replaced. when you click `no button`, the previous html will be returned. thats why I need that html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.string-publish-needle').click(function(e){

    var object = $(this);
    var object_path = object.attr('href');
    var object_parent = object.parent('li');
    var object_parents = object.parents('ul');
    var html_parents = object_parents.html();
    object_parent.remove();
    var html_remain = object_parents.html();

    alert(html_remain);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.string-publish-needle').click(function(e){
    var copy = $($('<ul/>').append($(this).parents('ul').html()));
    copy.find('.string-publish-needle').parent('li').remove();
    alert(copy.html());
});
```

Comment: I thought of that too. but I need to keep that element too. one is with that element another is without that element.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I have modified (untested), but something similar should work.

Comment: +1, you could also just do: `var copy = $(this).closest('ul').clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".string-publish-needle").click(function () {
          $(this).remove();
        });
```

Does this help ?

Comment: That's what I thought OP wanted.

Comment: I thought of that. but I need to keep that element too. one is with that element another is without that element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well...
but
you can do

```
$('.string-publish-needle').click(function(e) {

    var x = $(this).detach();

});
```

[detach function jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)